# MVC Long Web Service Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a system that calls a third party web service, using MVC. This service is based one a single record from a SQL Table.

The customer wants to change the spec, and now have a "batch" of records sent to the Web Service and get back the result.

For a small subset of records, this works but a lot of the time hundreds of records can be sent and this can take a long time (> 5 minutes). Some of the records, will also not be successful for various reasons, so after the process has run, I need to show the failed records and provide the ability to the user to "edit" the record, and then re-submit those that failed.

I have decided that I need to off load this process to another service (WebApi?) and poll that service to see when it completes but not sure where to begin.

Can anyone point in a direction?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue them in a table (either two tables (queue and outcome) or one table (queue with outcome column); either depend on how complex your data is). To process it, look at either a separate service (more scalable as you could add more worker services to complete larger work loads), or something like Quartz.net (if you want to keep it in one app).

As long as you build out without reliance on state/connections, you could scale reasonably well (add more workers during peak times or to process larger work loads should the app grow).

If the UI is a concern, you could also look into something like SignalR to notify the user the job has finished.

Answer (score 0):

`Web API` or `ASP.NET MVC` is usually not a very good option for long running processes. It's not reliable to wait for an HTTP request to complete and you can't use background threads to process your data because web server (if it is IIS) may decide to recycle application pool and your processing thread will be suspended.

It supposed to be a background worker job. You can put your pending items into a queue or a database and take them one by one for processing in your worker app. The result of processing can be pushed into the database.